# Showing dark bar with Theme.Light

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme

I have a problem. This is the dialog I get with my code:

http://es.tinypic.com/r/9acvbl/8

But I want the bar with the title "Modificación" to be white with a blue line below (I think the theme is Theme.Light).

Well, in the Manifest all the activities are:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

And for the layout of the dialog, I have selected in the drop-down menu, as you can imagine, Theme.Light. I also need to say that I have change manually the styles.xml for API 11+ and API 14+ to:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
```

Why it is showing a dark bar and not the light one?

---------SOLVED!!!-------------------------------------------

It was as easy (it took me all day long) as change the value in the styles.xml for API 14+ (folder values-v14):

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen">
```

It seems that for API 14+ the theme Theme.Light has no effect, so it was taking another theme. If you need it just in a specific activity, you can modify the style for that activity in the Manifest or you can write this code at the beginning of the onCreate of that activity:

```
int sdkVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT; // e.g. sdkVersion := 8;
if (sdkVersion >= 14) {
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_NoActionBar_Fullscreen);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for dialog,

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(
        context, android.R.style.Theme.Light));
```